# Remove columns with lowest variance

Tags: r

I have a large matrix of low values, such as:

```r
m <- matrix(c(0.000000217, 0.000000021, 0.000000403, 0.000000272,
              0.000000209, 0.000000310, 0.000000161, 0.000000243,
              0.000000375, 0.000000185, 0.000000298, 0.000000269),
            nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
```

In what I'm working on, columns with low variance are causing issues. My actual matrix has over 7,000 rows. How can I remove the bottom *n* columns of variance? I've tried various iterations of `apply()` with no success.

Comment: `m[,head(order(apply(m, 2, var), decreasing = TRUE), -n)]`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to calculate the variance for all columns and remove the `n` lowest variance columns?

Comment: You could check out `matrixStats::colVars` to get the variances

Comment: @d.b Thanks, that did it. As a side note, I ended up dropping the columns by percentile, so instead of `-n` I used `-0.2 * ncol(m)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
m <- matrix(c(0.000000217, 0.000000021, 0.000000403, 0.000000272,
              0.000000209, 0.000000310, 0.000000161, 0.000000243,
              0.000000375, 0.000000185, 0.000000298, 0.000000269),
            nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
```

Use `apply` and `var` to get column variances, and `order` and `head` to get the top or bottom *n*.

```r
m[, head(order(apply(m, 2, var), decreasing = TRUE), -n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `%in%` and `which.min`

```
m[,c(1:length(m[1,]))[!(c(1:length(m[1,])) %in% which.min(apply(m, 2, var)))]]
```